# Iterate through every possible combination of true and false?

Tags: math, combinatorics

Let's say I have 4 booleans.

How do I make a for loop that iterates through every possible combination, like

```
1000
0100
0010
0001
1100//etc...
```

Comment: Do you want to implement something in a specific programming language? There are sevral ways to generate that lookup, greatly depending on the context.

Comment: @Codor I don't really care for the language, I'd just like to see the logic behind it.

Comment: Simply count from 0 through 15, and use bitwise operators to extract bit 0 through 3.

Answer (score 0):

If the programming language is of no concern, there are at least two possibilities to generate the list of combinations.

First  enumeration of  the bit patterns in an integral type which can be done as follows.

```
1. Let n be the number of boolean variables.
2. Enumerate each number from 0 to 2^n-1.
3. For each of these numbers, say e, generate an assignment of the
   boolean variables where the i-th variable is assigned true
   if and only if the i-th bit of e is set.
4. Save each of these assignments.
```

Second by iteratively generating the assignments which can be done as follows.

```
1. Initialize a list l with one entry; the single entry
   represents a potential assignment of the variables.
2. While there are entries in the list in which there is an unassigned
   variable, execute the following steps, where c is a list of candidate assignments.
3. For each entry in l which has an unassigned variable, say e, generate two entries in c,
   namely one where the unassigned variable is set to true and one in
   which it is set to false. Remove e from l.
4. Merge the candidate list c into l.
```